# MIPS How to branch to a 32-bit address?

Tags: mips

I am trying to branch to an address:

```
bne $t0, $0, 0x7813a21c
```

However, this is incorrect because bne only allocates 16-bits to the immediate

How can I branch to a direct 32-bit address? Is there a way to branch from a value in a register?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `JR` to jump to an address stored in a register.

Comment: but this is unconditional. i would like to be able to branch to a 32-bit address.

Comment: Load the register with a value that you choose based on a condition.

Answer (score 0):

To preform this type of operation you will need a jump statement. You have to tell the code to jump control context to the exact line you wish to specify. This is example syntax: `j     offset` Where in your address is the offset.

Here is a link that better reviews what you have to do. Check out the section on jump. These are the types of jump available. One of them is what you need: `j     offset`, `jal   offset`, `jr    $rs`, `jalr  $rs`

Here is the link:
http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/jump.html

Good luck

Comment: `j offset` can only be used to jump within the current 256MByte region. You need to use a `jr` instruction to jump to an arbitrary 32 bit address.

Answer (score 0):

We can load 32-bit addresss to the register (e.g. `$t1`) in 2 steps:

1. Load the upper 16 bits by `lui` (Load Upper Immediate).
2. Load the lower 16 bits by `ori` (Or Immediate).

NOTE: It is work because `lui` fills the lower 16 bits with 0s, so bitwise OR *load* the lower 16 bits (n | 0 = n);

In code below if `$t0` is *equal* to 0 we *do* skip `jr` instruction.
Or if `$t0` is *not* equal to 0 we do *not* skip `jr` instruction (or we *do* jump).

```
      beq $t0, $0, SKIP

      # load 0x7813a21c to $t0

      lui  $t1, 0x7813 # load the upper 16 bits
      # Now $t1 = 0x78130000

      ori  $t1, $1, 0xa21c # load the lower 16 bits
      # Now $t1 = 0x7813A21C

      jr   $t1 # as @Matt Eckert said
SKIP:
```