# MIPS Branch instruction jumping beyond range

Tags: mips

I understand that in MIPs for PC-Addressing there is a maximum jump range. However, what if the address I wanted to jump to was beyond the range?

i.e. `beq $s0, $s1, L1`

where L1 is father away from the PC than can be supported by `bne` and `beq`. Is there any way I can construct an equivalent code sequence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIPS How to branch to a 32-bit address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937174/mips-how-to-branch-to-a-32-bit-address)

Comment: @RaymondChen this is not the question i’m asking. I’m not trying to “branch to a 32 bit address”. Right now my immediate is using PC Addressing, and I’m trying to ask if there is a way I can jump beyond the way of PC addressing using a different code sequence compared to the one I’m using, which is a direct jump beyond the range.

Comment: Sorry. If the instruction you want to use cannot reach your desired target, you'll have to switch to some type of jump instruction that can, hence my offered duplicate which contained suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the 16 bits of the I-Type command isn't enough for L1 you can use the J-Type since it has 26 bits for your address (just build your if around it).[MIPS I-Type vs J-Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMvlq.png)

If this still isn't enough you should save your address to a register using:`la $t0, L1`
and then jump to that register using: `jr $t0`
If you safe it to a register first, you have your full 32 bit address.